# Foxit Reader doesn't take focus on opening a file in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, focus, foxitreader

I'm using Foxit Reader as my default pdf reader in Ubuntu 18.04. However, if I open a pdf from file explorer, the pdf will be opened in Foxit Reader in background. I need to manually switch to Foxit Reader. Is this a bug or is it a setting that can be changed?